# How to get a margin around the page without content being pushed out

Tags: css

I want to have a somewhat fluid site where the min-width would be 1000px and the maximum width would be 1200px. Can someone either show me how to do this or point me to a tutorial?

The issue that I was having was that if I gave a 10px margin on the body, whatever was on the page was being pushed off the right side of the page by 10px. How do I correct this?

Comment: Can you show us some? So it will be helpful to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one good website that should help you to see the CSS for creating a fluid and fixed layout website-

http://csslayoutgenerator.com/

Regarding your 10px margin issue, here is a Test fiddle- [(CLICK here)](http://jsfiddle.net/DJdQd/), that I have made. What is the issue in it?

css-

```
body
{
    margin:10px;
    min-width:400px; 
    max-width:450px;
}
#test
{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as the Fiddle, Cdeez. It helped me.

Comment: If I may ask you another question before I go... I have other elements within my wrapper, such as an image rule. These rules are all currently set to repeat-x for the length of the parent. Will I need to change or add the min-width/max-width to all of these elements as well?

Comment: Also Cdeez, I just noticed that you have the min-width/max-width on the body element. I currently have that set to 100% width and margin and padding are set to '0'. Can I add these properties to my page wrapper element instead?

Comment: Block elements automatically take up the width available so you shouldn't have an issue with them. However the IMG tag elements are inline-block's and not sure about their behavior with a repeat-x background. Go ahead and experiment with the fiddle.

Comment: Yes you can set them to your wrapper element without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply your margin, only if your width if more than a specific value, you can use media queries :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the `border-box` property to you're element. This ensures that no matter what border, margin, or padding you place on the element, it will always produce a width that you specify

```
#element{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
min-width:1000px;
max-width:1200px;
}
```